# There is a unique polynomial $q_A(x)$ with a leading $1$ and degree $k$ such that $q_A(A)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A_{n\times n}$. Show there is a $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and a polynomial $q_A(x)$ with a leading $1$ coefficient and least degree $k$ such that $q_A(A)=0$.

If I recall correctly, this is the minimal polynomial of $A$, and the result follows my showing there exists a $k$ such that $I, A, A^2,...,A^k$ are linearly dependent. Can anyone offer a simple explanation of a proof of this problem?

Comment: To my knowledge, the argument you have given *is* this the simplest there is.

Comment: @k.stm Do you know where I can find a proof of this argument?

Comment: I think you might consider re-phrasing the question to say that there exists $k$ such that $I, A, A^2, \ldots, A^k$ are linearly *dependent*.  Otherwise . . . ?

Comment: @RobertLewis You're correct, sorry about that.

Comment: Congratulations on the swift editing!  Nice question, ***plus one!***

Comment: @RobertLewis two letters removed and the rest remain, a +1 results- a wonderful gain. Yet, the question still unsolved for all to see, on this wonderful network offering answers for free! Thank you!

Comment: I'm writing up an answer at present.  Should post shortly!

Comment: @RobertLewis Thank you! Although unrelated to this question, I'm really enjoying browsing around your page. Rock on :)

Comment: That's quite alright, I really appreciate the effort. And yes! I play classical guitar, so it's nice to see such a brilliant mind with a strong love for music :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wealll, let $\Bbb F$ be *any* field and let $M_n(\Bbb F)$ be the vector space of $n \times n$ matrices over $\Bbb F$.  I claim the dimension of $M_n(\Bbb F)$ over $\Bbb F$ is precisely $n^2$.  This is easy to see:  indeed, the $n^2$ matrices $E_{ij}$ form a basis for $M_n(\Bbb F)$, where $E_{ij}$ is matrix whose $ij$ entry is $1$  and whose other entries are $0$.  The set $\mathcal E = \{ E_{ij} \mid 1 \le i, j \le n \}$ clearly spans $M_n(\Bbb F)$, since for any $A = [A_{ij}] \in M_n(\Bbb F)$ we may write

$A = \sum_{i, j = 1}^n A_
{ij} E_{ij}; \tag{1}$

the same formula shows the $E_{ij}$ are linearly independent since

$\sum_{i,j = 1}^n A_{ij} E_{ij} = 0 \tag{2}$

if and only if the matrix $A = 0$, i.e., $A_{ij} = 0$ for all $i, j$; we have thus  shown that  $\mathcal E$ is a basis for $M_n(\Bbb F)$, and thus that

$\dim M_n(\Bbb F) = n^2 < \infty. \tag{3}$

Returning to the powers $A^i$ of the matrix $A$, we see from (3) that the sequence $I$, $A$, $A^2$, $\ldots$, $A^{n^2}$ of matrices, consisting as it does of $n^2 + 1$ elements of $M_n(\Bbb F)$, must be linearly *dependent*; that is, there is a sequence of $n^2 + 1$ elements $c_i \in \Bbb F$, $1 \le i \le n^2$, such that

$\sum_0^{n^2} c_i A^i = 0; \tag{4}$

(4) shows that $A$ satisfies the polynomial

$p(x) = \sum_0^{n^2} c_i x^i \in \Bbb F[x]. \tag{5}$

Having established that $A$ satisfies *some* polynomial in $\Bbb F[x]$, we conlude there is a polynomial $q_A(x) \in \Bbb[x]$ of minimal degree $k \le n^2$ with

$q_A(A) = \sum_0^k q_i A^i = 0; \tag{6}$

since $\Bbb F$ is a field, we may if necessary divide $q_A(x)$ through by $q_k \ne 0$ (since $\deg q = k$) and thus take $q_A(x)$ to be monic.  The uniqueness of such $q_A(x)$ may then be seen as follows:  if $p(x) \in \Bbb F[x]$ is monic of degree $k$ and $p(A) = 0$, we may by the Euclidean algorithm, which holds in $F[x]$ for any field $\Bbb F$, write

$p(x) = d(x) q_A(x) + r(x), \tag{7}$

$d(x), r(x) \in \Bbb F[x]$, where if $r(x) \ne 0$ we have $\deg r <  \deg q_A = k$.  But then

$r(A) = p(A) - d(A)q_A(A) = 0, \tag{8}$

and since $\deg r < k$ the minimality of $k$ forces $r(x) = 0$.  Since $p(x)$ and $q_A(x)$ are both monic of degree $k$ we must then have $d(x) = 1$ and hence $p(x) = q_A(x)$; the minimal polynomial $q_A(x)$ of $A$ is thus unique.  And this over any field $\Bbb F$.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheers!

And as ever,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

᤾